# Earth, Mirrored-Earth and aliens finding their location

Tags: biology, physics, aliens, communication

There is our Earth. In a nearby galaxy there is Mirrored-Earth, much like our planet, with the exception that humans there are flipped left-right wise - so e.g. their hearts are mostly on the right side.

We send a description of a human to aliens that have never seen humans or mirrored humans but are aware of their existence and their planets. The description is of human and human only - not in a context of other objects or surroundings.

After receiving our description, one alien fiends themself on either Earth or Mirrored-Earth - they don't know which one. Having noticed a human and scanned their body with their X-ray eyes, do they know whether they are on Earth or Mirrored-Earth?

- Edit *

What I am in essence asking about is how to (simply, if possible) convey meaning of our left and right to aliens that do not have our earthly frame of reference.

- Edit 2 *

I found this question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/730440/explaining-left-and-right-to-an-alien-using-chirality-and-helicity (thanks @AlexP for link to a resource with proper terminology).

Does this mean there are no high-tech means of conveying meaning of local left-right?

Comment: What has this to do with worldbuilding?

Comment: If we sent them a description of Earth-humans, they will surely know that, for example, the aorta curves to the left. As part of the description we surely told them what we call right and what we call left. When they find one of Earth or Mirrored-Earth, they will scan the locals and find whether their aortas curve to the left or to the right. What is the difficulty? (Yes, perhaps suprisingly, left and right have [absolute meanings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(physics)), as [demonstrated experimentally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wu_experiment) by Chien-Shiung Wu in 1956.)

Comment: What’s the question to be answered here?  I think the name of the account is kind of fishy, makes me suspect this is just trolling.

Comment: @AlexP So that's the rub - how to convey what is left and what is right? Does it mean then we would have to describe left and right in terms of say a weak force?

L.Dutch That's mostly about how to conduct communication.

Comment: Of course we describe left and right in terms of the weak force. There is no other way. The electromagnetic and gravitational interactions conserve parity, so that as far as electromagnetic and gravitational forces are concerned, a mirrored world is indistinguishable from a mirror image of the normal world; but weak force interactions break the symmetry. But the question says that the only difference is that the *humans* are flipped; if their amino-acids and sugars are the same as ours, then we can refer left and right to the chirality of the molecules, which we need to specify anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a long while since I've seen it in any depth, but whether the right-hand rule applies to a (chosen, simple) coordinate system or not is an objective mathematical fact, and thus could be communicated to aliens.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule

Work backwards from there to "what is a right hand".